# Is the strage narration "...you should praise Allah and your anus" authentic?

Tags: authenticity, ali

Is this strange narration authentic?!

> One day ‘Ali attacked Amr ibn Aas, he threw a spear and Amr fell to the ground, Amr fell to the ground and he then exposed his buttocks. ‘Ali then turned away his face [people said] this was Amr bin Aas. ‘Ali replied he showed me his anus and this made me merciful to him. When Amr ibn Aas returned, Mu’awiya said ‘You should praise Allah and your anus”.

Al Bidayah wa al Nihayah, Volume 7 page 293

It's been mentioned on [ShiaChat](http://www.shiachat.com/forum/topic/235036408-muawiyah/) and it's listed at [PurifiedHousehold.com](http://purifiedhousehold.com/imam-ali-as-refutes-sunni-hadith/) who supply the following:

[image]

Comment: A hadith scholar like al-hafidh ibn Kathir would have added his qualification of a narration or a narrator chain or source. So why you post only a quote without context?

Comment: I don't have access to English translation of this book, i found this hadith on a Shia site and need clarification, I'am not quoting out of context so idk what ibn kathir qualification is...

Comment: Im not quoting out of context i found some of these questions in anti muslims sites or shia sites so i come here to get clarification, to know if these narrations are authentic. For the purpose of edification i want to defend my faith from islamophobes and study ahadeeths.

Comment: @Ali - Any updates about this narration?